# How to verify password field in zend form?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

In my form, I'm trying to verify that the user fills in the same value both times (to make sure they didn't make a mistake). I think that's what `Zend_Validate_Identical` is for, but I'm not quite sure how to use it. Here's what I've got so far:

```
$this->addElement('password', 'password', array(
        'label'      => 'Password:',
        'required'   => true,
        'validators' => array(
            'Identical' => array(What do I put here?)
        )
    ));
$this->addElement('password', 'verifypassword', array(
        'label'      => 'Verify Password:',
        'required'   => true,
        'validators' => array(
            'Identical' => array(What do I put here?)
        )
    ));
```

Do I need it on both elements? What do I put in the array?

Comment: Up to date answer using Zend_Validate_Identical and another element as the 'token': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628606/how-to-verify-password-field-in-zend-form/3653416#3653416

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For what its worth, support for comparing two identical form fields within a model was added to the 1.10.5 release. I wrote up a short tutorial on the matter, which you can access via the below link, but the bottom line is that the Zend_Validate_Identical validator has been refactored to accept a form field name as input. For instance, to compare the values of form fields pswd and confirm_pswd, you'll attach the validator to confirm_pswd like so:

```
$confirmPswd->addValidator('Identical', false, array('token' => 'pswd'));
```

Works like a charm.

See [Validating Identical Passwords with the Zend Framework](http://www.wjgilmore.com/blog/entry/validating_identical_passwords_with_the_zend_framework) for a more complete example.

Comment: How can I use this for both add and edit operation @ Jason , @saji89

Answer (score 5):

I can't test it at the moment, but I think this might work:

```
$this->addElement('password', 'password', array(
    'label'      => 'Password:',
    'required'   => true
));
$this->addElement('password', 'verifypassword', array(
    'label'      => 'Verify Password:',
    'required'   => true,
    'validators' => array(
        array('identical', true, array('password'))
    )
));
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: The token 'password' does not match the given token 'testpassword'. testpassword is the value and password is the name of the element that was specified here: 'identical', true, array('password')

Comment: I was about to say that it was weird that it displayed the value of the password I entered in the error message, but turns out that's not true because I had set the element type as text and not password.

Answer (score 2):

After two days I found the right answer follow me step by step:

**step 1:**

create `PasswordConfirmation.php` file in root directory of your project with this path:
`yourproject/My/Validate/PasswordConfirmation.php` with this content below:

```
<?php 
require_once 'Zend/Validate/Abstract.php';
class My_Validate_PasswordConfirmation extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
    const NOT_MATCH = 'notMatch';

    protected $_messageTemplates = array(
        self::NOT_MATCH => 'Password confirmation does not match'
    );

    public function isValid($value, $context = null)
    {
        $value = (string) $value;
        $this->_setValue($value);

        if (is_array($context)) {
            if (isset($context['user_password']) 
               && ($value == $context['user_password']))
            {
                return true;
            }
        } 
        elseif (is_string($context) && ($value == $context)) {
            return true;
        }

        $this->_error(self::NOT_MATCH);
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

**step 2:**

Add two field in your form like this:

```
//create the form elements user_password
$userPassword = $this->createElement('password', 'user_password');
$userPassword->setLabel('Password: ');
$userPassword->setRequired('true');
$this->addElement($userPassword);

//create the form elements user_password repeat
$userPasswordRepeat = $this->createElement('password', 'user_password_confirm');
$userPasswordRepeat->setLabel('Password repeat: ');
$userPasswordRepeat->setRequired('true');
$userPasswordRepeat->addPrefixPath('My_Validate', 'My/Validate', 'validate');
$userPasswordRepeat->addValidator('PasswordConfirmation', true, array('user_password'));
$this->addElement($userPasswordRepeat);
```

now enjoy your code

Comment: @moinsam ,If I have an edit/update option along with add the what changes should be made ?

Answer (score 1):

```
class My_Validate_PasswordConfirmation extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
const NOT_MATCH = 'notMatch';

protected $_messageTemplates = array(
    self::NOT_MATCH => 'Password confirmation does not match'
);

public function isValid($value, $context = null)
{
    $value = (string) $value;
    $this->_setValue($value);

    if (is_array($context)) {
        if (isset($context['password_confirm'])
            && ($value == $context['password_confirm']))
        {
            return true;
        }
    } elseif (is_string($context) && ($value == $context)) {
        return true;
    }

    $this->_error(self::NOT_MATCH);
    return false;
}
}
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$token = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getPost('password');
$confirmPassword->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Identical(trim($token)))
                  ->addFilter(new Zend_Filter_StringTrim())
                  ->isRequired();
```

Use the above code inside the class which extends zend_form.

Comment: cant we use $password->getValue() ?
well i have already tried but i got empty value.. why is it so? if getValue is method of that element then it should have returned the value of the password?

Comment: that because  getValue() is getting called before $form->isValid($_POST); since that code is inside constructor or init method .

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with the following code:

In my form I add the Identical validator on the second element only:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'email', array(
        'label'      => 'Email address:',
        'required'   => true,
        'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
        'validators' => array('EmailAddress')
    ));

$this->addElement('text', 'verify_email', array(
        'label'      => 'Verify Email:',
        'required'   => true,
        'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
        'validators' => array('EmailAddress', 'Identical')
    ));
```

And in the controller, just before calling `isValid()`:

```
$validator = $form->getElement('verify_email')->getValidator('identical');
$validator->setToken($this->_request->getPost('email'));
```

I don't know if there is a more elegant way of doing this without having to add this code to the controller. Let me know if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

With **Zend Framework 1.10** the code needed to validate the equality of two fields using **Zend Form** and **Zend Validate** is:

```
    $form->addElement('PasswordTextBox',
                      'password',
                      array('label'      => 'Password')
                      );

    $form->addElement('PasswordTextBox',
                      'password_confirm',
                      array('label'      => 'Confirm password',
                            'validators' => array(array('Identical', false, 'password')),
                            )
                      );
```

You can notice, in the validators array of the `password_confirm` element, that the `Identical` validator is passed as array, the semantics of that array is: *i) Validator name, ii) break chain on failure, iii) validator options*
As you can see, it's possible to pass the field name instead of retrieving the value.