# Zend_Form: identical fields returning false when actually identical

Tags: validation, zend-framework, zend-form, password-confirmation

I've been struggling with this for an hour now and still can't understand what's wrong.
Here's how I set my two fields:

```
$password = $this->createElement('password', 'password');
$password->setLabel('Password');
$password->setRequired('true');
$password->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Regex('/^([a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9]+[a-z]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*)|([a-zA-Z0-9]*[A-Z]+[a-z]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*)$/'));
$password->setAttrib('size', 25);
$password->setAttrib('length', 150);
$this->addElement($password);

$confirm_password = $this->createElement('password', 'confirm_password');
$confirm_password->setLabel('Confirm');
$confirm_password->setRequired('true');
$confirm_password->setAttrib('size', 25);
$confirm_password->setAttrib('length', 150);

$confirm_password->addValidator('Identical', false, array('token' => 'password'));
//$confirm_password->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Identical(array('token' => 'password')));

$this->addElement($confirm_password);
```

I've tried both validators (+ the one commented) but none works.
These declarations come from [www.wjgilmore.com/blog/entry/validating_identical_passwords_with_the_zend_framework](http://www.wjgilmore.com/blog/entry/validating_identical_passwords_with_the_zend_framework) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653416/1300454

Both declarations always return "The two given tokens do not match" eventho I'm sure these two fields contain the exact same string.

Any guess ? Thank you!

**EDIT**:
just noticed thanks to XDebug that when `Zend_Validate_Identical`'s `isValid()` function is called, my `$token` equals 'password' while my `$value` equals 'P4ssword' (the password I entered in my confirm_password field. What's going on?

**EDIT2**:
tried with these two solutions: [emanaton.com/code/php/validateidenticalfield](http://emanaton.com/code/php/validateidenticalfield) and [stackoverflow.com/a/1628611/1300454](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1628611/1300454) but none of them work for me either. With the generic IdenticalField validator it can't find my "password" field and the second validator just returns that the two field don't match and with XDebug again I found out that it's still looking to match my password 'P4ssword' to the word 'password' that I gave as the field name...

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're not using current Zend Framework version? The code in the class looks like it should work as you expect it (1.11). Are you using $form->isValid() or ->isValidPartial()? Try editing the code of ZF and dumping the contents of $context variable. It looks like your code is not filling the $context variable as it should.

```
public function isValid($value, $context = null)
{
    $this->_setValue((string) $value);

    if (($context !== null) && isset($context) && array_key_exists($this->getToken(), $context)) {
        $token = $context[$this->getToken()];
    } else {
        $token = $this->getToken();
    }

    if ($token === null) {
        $this->_error(self::MISSING_TOKEN);
        return false;
    }

    $strict = $this->getStrict();
    if (($strict && ($value !== $token)) || (!$strict && ($value != $token))) {
        $this->_error(self::NOT_SAME);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: is there a way I could for sure tell what version I'm using ?

Comment: $context contains:
('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'dovalidation', 'module' => 'default', 'confirm_password' => 'P4ssword')

Comment: Than from my point of view the problem is you set the validator to password element, instead of confirm_password. The password value is in $value and confirm is in $context. You can either move the validator or change the token to confirm_password

Comment: I didn't really understand what you were saying. Did you mean I should add the validator to 'password' element or did you imply that I do it by mistake? Because my code is exactly how it looks in my question. Btw, I've also tried to put it on password element before but doesn't work any better. Weird stuff.